# Syntax of "return +(test) && recursion"

Tags: javascript

```
const sequenceSum = (b, e, s) => +(b <= e) && b + sequenceSum(b+s, e, s);
```

I don't understand how the plus sign before the test along with `&&` evaluates. The expectation is that this function will in fact return one or the other rather then "this and this". If b <= e then the function is expected to return 0.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: I unclear about the purpose of getting 0 or 1 out of the test.

Comment: In that case the question falls back to [Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_())

Comment: So it takes 0 for false and will "preffer" that to the recursion return? Or in fact will also return that last value of the && values should the first test evaluate to true.